# Multiple Selections from Dropdown in Word 2011 Form

Tags: microsoft-word-2011

Anyone know if there is a way to setup a Word form to allow the user to select multiple items from a dropdown list that are then displayed? For example, I need to setup a form to identify applicability of specific procedures to various levels of our organization. Since the listing of all departments under all divisions can be pretty lengthy, I was hoping for the ability to check off a division and then have a dropdown list on the same line to select the applicable departments (so the selections are specific to that division and not all listed on the form if that division is not applicable).

First, I'm not seeing how to create a dropdown that would allow multiple selections. Beyond that, I don't know if that form element alone would then display all selected items or if that would require another element of some type.

Anyone have any suggestions on this? Thanks in advance!